# Laravel Eloquent paginate how to query pagination parameters?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a Laravel project that has an API.  Some endpoint controllers use pagination for the index.

I would like to expose the pagination parameters to the client.
The reason is so they wouldn't have to always ask for the first item, just to figure out how many items per page there will be (for instance if the client wants to skip the first X items for some reason).

I've tried `paginate(0)` but this gives the default of 16 items.

Is there an easy built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the [Paginator results to JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#converting-results-to-json). Doing so, you'll get some meta data, including the total number of items, number of pages, current page, etc.

According to the linked page, if we have a route like this:

```
Route::get('users', function () {
    return App\User::paginate();
});
```

It would return something like this:

```
{
   "total": 50,
   "per_page": 15,
   "current_page": 1,
   "last_page": 4,
   "next_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=2",
   "prev_page_url": null,
   "from": 1,
   "to": 15,
   "data":[
        {
            // Result Object
        },
        {
            // Result Object
        }
   ]
}
```

I think that this would be what you're looking for.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi Erick, thanks for the reply.  I tried that, but `paginate()` returns the default number of items (15).  I was trying to avoid getting the data from the database if it wasn't needed.

Comment: Hmmm, so I tried the exact example you showed, and it did work.  I must be doing something in my actual query ahead of time that is causing the results to be retrieved.

Comment: I see. So, If anything pops up, just ask again :)

Comment: Oh wait, the answer you showed also has data.  See the data part in the bottom?  I don't want to return data.  Would there be a way to return the pagination information, without actually getting the data from the database?

Comment: Well, I think that, unless you have a cache system for that, you'll need to touch the DB to get the most recent amount of data.